# Show that the closure of $A$ is the intersection of all closed sets containing $A$, topology proof needed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I want to show that given $(X, \mathcal{T})$, we define $\overline A = \{x \in X| \forall U \in \mathcal{T}, x \in U \implies U \cap A \neq \varnothing\}$ (definition of closure from Munkres), then

> Show that $\overline A = \bigcap\{C \subseteq X | C \text{ is closed }, A
> \subseteq C\}$

I find this really hard to tackle because some unnaturalness in that $\overline A$ is specified with respect to open sets, but then it is alternatively defined as intersection of closed sets..how to juggle between open and closed?

Several other posts also doesn't help...

1. [The closure of A is the smalled closed set containing A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1204259/the-closure-of-a-is-the-smalled-closed-set-containing-a) is proved in terms of accumulation points and limit points which I do not define
2. [Proving that the closure of a subset is the intersection of the closed subsets containing it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55658/proving-that-the-closure-of-a-subset-is-the-intersection-of-the-closed-subsets-c) is defined wrt of metric spaces

*I am stuck on both inclusions and need some help*

**Attempt**:

### $(\overline A \subseteq \bigcap\{C \subseteq X | C \text{ is closed }, A
\subseteq C\})$

---

- Let $x \in \overline A$, then $\forall U \in \tau, x \in U \implies A
     \cap U \neq \varnothing$. We want to show that $x \in \bigcap\{C
     \subseteq X | C \text{ is closed }, A \subseteq C\}$
- So we know that $x$ is contained in some $U' \in \mathcal{T}$ that
  has non-empty intersection with $A$, $x$ not necessarily in $A$.
- Let $C_1$ be a closed set containing $A$, then $U' \cap C_1 \neq
     \varnothing$.  Let $C_2$ be a closed set containing $A$, then $U'
     \cap C_2 \neq \varnothing$. Assuming $C_1 \subseteq C_2$, then   $U'
     \cap C_1 \cap C_2 \neq \varnothing$.
- Continue this way, $U' \cap \bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in I} C_\alpha
     \neq \varnothing$, where $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in I} C_\alpha$ is
  the intersection of all closed sets containing $A$
- We know already that $x \in U'$, but from above how can we see that $x
     \in \bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in I} C_\alpha$? From figure below, it
  seems that $x$ will not be in $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in I}
     C_\alpha$

[image]

### $( \bigcap\{C \subseteq X | C \text{ is closed }, A
\subseteq C\} \subseteq \overline A)$

- Let $x \in  \bigcap\{C \subseteq X | C \text{ is closed }, A
     \subseteq C\}$, we want to show that $x \in \overline A$. It suffices
  to show that $\forall U \in \mathcal{T}, x \in U \implies U \in A
     \neq \varnothing$.
- Since $x \in \bigcap \{C\}$, then there exists some closed set $C'
     \subseteq X$ such that $x \in C'$. Let $U \in \mathcal{T}$ containing
  $x$, then we will show that $U \cap A \neq \varnothing$
- We know that $x \in C' \cap U$, then $x \in \bigcap{C} \cap U$. At this point however I still don't know whether $U \cap A \neq \varnothing$. Couldn't we have a case in figure below where $x \in \bigcap \{C\}$ and $x \in U$, but $U \cap A = \varnothing$?

[image]

Comment: Hint: For the second inclusion you only need to know that $\overline{A}$ is closed.

Comment: For the other inclusion assume $x \notin \overline{A}$. I.e. you have an open $U$ containing $x$ which has trivial intersection with $A$. Keep in mind that the complement of an open set is closed.

Comment: A limit point is just a member of the closure that is not in the interior.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You’re getting bogged down in the details of the definitions and thereby making it much harder than it really is.

For the first inclusion, start, as you did, with an arbitrary $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$. Let $C$ be any closed set such that $A\subseteq C$. Suppose that $x\notin C$: then $x\in X\setminus C$, and $X\setminus C$ is open, so $(X\setminus C)\cap A\ne\varnothing$. But on the other hand we know that $A\subseteq C$, so $A\cap(X\setminus C)=\varnothing$. This contradiction shows that $x\in C$, and since $C$ was an arbitrary closed set containing $A$, we conclude that

$$\operatorname{cl}A\subseteq\bigcap\{C\subseteq X:A\subseteq C\text{ and }C\text{ is closed}\}\;.$$

For the opposite inclusion just observe that $\operatorname{cl}A$ **is** one of the closed sets containing $A$, so if $x\in\bigcap\{C\subseteq X:A\subseteq C\text{ and }C\text{ is closed}\}$, then automatically $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$. It follows that

$$\bigcap\{C\subseteq X:A\subseteq C\text{ and }C\text{ is closed}\}\subseteq\operatorname{cl}A$$

and hence that

$$\bigcap\{C\subseteq X:A\subseteq C\text{ and }C\text{ is closed}\}=\operatorname{cl}A\;.$$

Comment: wow perfect solution

Comment: @Brian M. Scott, can you please explain the part "$(X\setminus C)\cap A\ne\varnothing$"? you claim it's not $\varnothing$  because based on the definition of closure of $A$ , $x \in A$?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will help:

Definitions:

$A'$ is the set of all accumulation or limit points.

$\overline{A} = A \cup A'$ - this is known as the closure of $A$.

> $\bar{A}$ is closed.

Proof - Suppose $p$ is not in $\bar{A}$. Since $p$ is not in $\overline{A}$, it is not in $A$ nor is it a limit point of $A$. Therefore there must be some neighborhood $N$ of $p$ that does not intersect $A$ at all.

Can $N$ contain any limit points of $A$? No. If it contained one, $a$. Then by definition of limit point $N$ must contain another point of $A$. But $N$ contains no points of $A$, so this is ridiculous. Thus $N$ must be disjoint from both $A$ and its set of limit points, so $N \subseteq \overline{A}^c$, as desired. Thus the compliment of the closure is open, so the closure is closed.

Comment: thanks but I am just honestly not taught what a limit point is

Comment: would you like me to expand upon my answer to include information on what a limit point is?

Comment: Oh no that's okay, I have Munkres as reference and I think I am the only person who studies topology without knowing what limit point is. I think other people can easily understand your proof. My prof do not wish for us to know what limit point is he thinks it is detriment to learning topology...

Comment: I see okay well best of luck

Comment: A limit point is just a member of the closure that is not in the interior.

Comment: @BeachedWhale Do you always do what your professor wants?

Answer (score 0):

All the points far from A form an open set (because it is a union of some open set for each of its points, definitionally). Moreover it is the largest open set without elements in A (for consider a neighborhood of a close point...) . Thus its complement, the closure, is the smallest closed set containing A.

Answer (score -1):

Let $x$ in $\bar{A}$. Note that $\bar{A}$ is closed, so $x$ is in a closed set. Suppose for some closed $C$ containing $A$ that $x$ is not in $C$. That means $x$ is in $C$'s complement, which is open. But that contradicts the fact that $x$ was in a closed set, so $x \in C$. Since $x$ was arbitrary in $\bar{A}$, and $C$ was an arbitrary member of all $C$ containing $A$, we have proved $\bar{A} \subset \mathscr{C}$, where the fancy "C" is the set of all closed sets containing $A$. Keep in mind that if a set exists in every one of a collection of sets, then it must also be in their intersection.

Now, for equality we need to show $\bar{A} \supset \bigcap{C}$. Let $x$ in $\bigcap C$. Suppose $x$ not in $\bar{A}$, then $x$ is in $\bar{A}^c$ which is open. But we just said $x$ is in an intersection of closed sets, so it must be in a closed set. Contradiction again.

---

The one gap in this proof is the fact that these sets could have been $\mathbb{R}^d$. But in that case equality is automatic.