# Show that the closure of B is the intersection of all closed sets containing B

Tags: general-topology

I'm preparing for a course on Topology next semester (so I am a beginner) and in Klaus Jänich's book "Topologie" the question above is asked which I cannot answer.

To give more details, the relevant definition is given as

Let X be a topological space.

1. $A \subset X$ is called closed when $X \setminus A$ is open
2. $U \subset X$ is called a neighbourhood of $x \in X$ of there is an open set V with $x \in V \subset U$.
3. Let $B \subset X$ be any subset. A point $x \in X$ is called an interior, exterior or boundary point of $B$, respectively, according to whether $B$, $X \setminus B$ or neither is a neighbourhood of $x$.
4. The set of the interior points of B is called the interior of B.
5. The set of the points points of X which are not exterior points of B is called the closure of B.

The book then states "Should among my readers be a complete newcomer to the field, I would suggest to them to verify right now that the interior of B is the union of all open sets contained in B, and that the closure of B is the intersection of all closed sets containing B".

As a diligent complete newcomer I've had a go at this. The first part I think I can at least justify in my head. My reasoning is that since the interior of B is given as all the interior points of B, where those interior points are defined if there is an open set V with $x \in V \subset U$, we essentially take the union of all these $V$ open sets to get the interior.

The second part, I cannot justify however as I don't see how the intersection comes into play. I can see that since the closure of B are not exterior points (so not those points $y \in V \subset X \setminus B$ for some open $V$), we get the interior and boundary points which makes sense given it's called closure. But I don't see how its the intersection of all closed sets containing B.

Can anyone advise how to approach this? Also, if anyone has any resources for simple questions like this could help me get some practice with this type of thinking - I would be very appreciative. Thank you.

Note: I see that my question is similar to [Show that the closure of $A$ is the intersection of all closed sets containing $A$, topology proof needed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1819839/show-that-the-closure-of-a-is-the-intersection-of-all-closed-sets-containing), but the definitions of closure are different so posting this. Happy to be corrected if this is a duplicate however.

Comment: Can you show that the closure is closed and contains $B$ (or equivalently, that the exterior is open)? You get one inclusion for free then. For the other direction, try to prove that $x$ is in the closure of $B$ if and only if every open set containing $x$ intersects $B$.

Comment: You've read the definition of closure incorrectly. It should read "...the closure of $B$ is the intersection of all closed sets *containing* $B$." This should solve the issue of where exterior points lie.

Comment: Sorry yes you're quite right. Question amended. Will give the other part of the comments some further thought.

Comment: Does the following show that the exterior is open?

Exterior is the collection of exterior points of B, i.e. those which have $X  \setminus B$ as a neighbourhood of $x$. Therefore there are open sets $V$ such that $x \in V \subset X \setminus B$. Taking all the exterior points of B is equivalent to taking the union of sets $V$ which too is open.

Comment: @JamesLevine Should work, you are basically showing that the interior of the complement is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $C$ is a closed set containing $B$. Then $X\setminus C$ is open, so it is a neighborhood of all of its points. Since $X\setminus C\subseteq X\setminus B$, this means that every point in $X\setminus C$ is an exterior point of $B$.

Thus, we have that
$$\begin{align*}
X\setminus \bigcap_{{B\subseteq C},\ {C\text{ closed}}} C &= 
\bigcup_{{B\subseteq C},\ {C\text{ closed}}} (X\setminus C)\\
&\subseteq \{x\in X\mid x\text{ is an exterior point of B}\}\\
&= X\setminus \mathrm{closure}(B).
\end{align*}$$

Conversely, let $x\in X\setminus\mathrm{closure}(B)$. Then $x$ is an exterior point of $B$, so $X\setminus B$ is a neighborhood of $x$. That means that there is an open set $\mathcal{O}$ such that $x\in\mathcal{O}\subseteq X\setminus B$. Then $C=X\setminus\mathcal{O}\supseteq X\setminus(X\setminus B)=B$ is closed and contains $B$; so $x\in X\setminus C$ for some closed set $C$ that contains $B$. Therefore,
$$\begin{align*}
X\setminus \mathrm{closure}(B) &= \{x\in X\mid x\text{ is an exterior point of }B\}\\
&\subseteq \bigcup_{B\subseteq C,\ C\text{ closed}}(X\setminus C)\\
&= X\setminus\bigcap_{B\subseteq C,\ C\text{ closed}}C,
\end{align*}$$

So we have equality between the complement of $\mathrm{closure}(B)$, and the complement of the intersection of all closed sets containing $B$. Taking complements again, we have
$$ \bigcap_{B\subseteq C,\ C\text{ closed}} C = \mathrm{closure}(B),$$
as desired.

Comment: Thank you - the question was more involved than I was expecting. May I quickly ask, does the result that $X \setminus \bigcap_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}$ = $\bigcup_{i =1}^{n} (X \setminus A_i)$ (which was used twice) hold generally - or is it specific to this scenario? From drawing a few venn diagrams and I can believe that it does.

Comment: @JamesLevine It's De Morgan's law: the complement of a union is the intersection of the complements, the complement of an intersection is the union of the complements.  And they don't have to be finite: mine are not necessarily finite, despite how you wrote them.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\overline B&=\{x\in X\mid x\text{ is not exterior to }B\}\\
&=\{x\in X\mid X\setminus B\text{ is not a neighborhood of }x\}\\
&=\{x\in X\mid\text{for every open subset }V\text{ contained in }X\setminus B,\; x\notin V\}\\
&=\{x\in X\mid\text{for every closed subset }A\text{ containing }B,\; x\in A\}\\
&=\bigcap_{A\text{ closed}\atop B\subseteq A}A
\end{align}$$